# Extjs binding value not getting cleared

Tags: extjs, binding, extjs6-classic

Extjs binding value not getting cleared  when the user clears the date field box manually ( user changes date field to blank )

I cannot post the code but i found a similar [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1dcv&view/editor)

In this fiddle i want the value to be cleared when i clear the datefield manually , instead what is happening is the display field keeps showing the old value

it would be great help if some one could provide me the solution

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`specialkey`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.form.field.Date.html#event-specialkey) event for the [`datefield`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.form.field.Date.html) to achieve the required result.

You can check here with working [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2nmq).

**Note** you can put your logic based on your requirement. I have just create simple example.

**Code snippet**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {

            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

            viewModel: {
                data: {
                    dateFrom: null,
                }
            },

            items: [{
                xtype: 'datefield',
                emptyText: 'Date From',
                bind: '{dateFrom}',
                listeners: {
                    specialkey: function (field, e) {
                        if (e.getKey() == e.DELETE || e.getKey() == e.BACKSPACE) {
                            field.up('panel').getViewModel().set('dateFrom', null);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'displayfield',
                bind: {
                    value: '{dateFrom}'
                }
            }]
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: Narendra Jadhav : thanks for suggested solution. The new problem is now its not at all allowing me to edit the date string (one backspace and all the date is deleted) i have to always select through the date picker.

Comment: yes you are right. As I have mentioned in solution it's just demo. You can put your logic. You find the way how to do it.